# Custom list widget

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'd like to know how to create a custom list widget like this using wxWidgets:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

All of them has an image, buttons and informations, how can I do a custom widget like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native control that would give you exactly this, so you would need to write your own composite control. This is not difficult to do for a flat list of items like in the last two examples but is slightly more challenging for an expandable list like in the first one.

If you want to avoid this, the only control that comes closer to what you want is [wxDataViewCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html) with which you can use custom renderers to customize the look of your cells. It only would make sense to use it if your data is either hierarchical or multi-column in nature (and especially if it is both).

Comment: You can ignore the expanding list on the first one, the idea was to show the list itself, the way that it's organized, with an image, texts and so on. - Is there a simple example using that wxDataViewCtrl? Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that this `wxDataViewCtrl` looks like the first example and it's not what I want, the listing can be like the second or third one, the item is what I want to customize.